# What is the Windows Forms equivalent of the WPF's Keyboard class?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, keyboard

Question says it all - is there a class somewhere in Windows Forms that has the same functionality as the WPF [`System.Windows.Input.Keyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx)?  Or am I stuck always having to handle the keyboard events and keep my own state?  (I'm specifically interested in a Forms analogue to [`IsKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown.aspx)).

Alternatively, is there a **no-fuss** way to use this WPF functionality in my Forms project (I'm not very familiar with WPF, but [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742474(VS.85).aspx) looks fussy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not averse to P/Invoke, you may want to take a look at the Windows API [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646301(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an equivalent for WinForms.  The best I know of is the static ModifierKeys property on Control but that is almost certainly not what you are looking for.

I believe you are stuck with handling the events and keeping your own state :(

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it? and why can't you simply use Windows.Input.Keyboard in your WinForms application? They are not incompatible, and can be used together. The only reason I can think of is that you need to target .NET 2.x platform and the client machines do not have .NET 3.x installed.

Comment: See the "fuss" part of my original question and included link - using both WPF and WinForms functionality simultaneously is non-trivial it would appear.